# How can several users work on the same Enterprise architect file?

Tags: odbc, collaboration, enterprise-architect

I'm wondering if many users can work on the same Enterprise Architect file ? our professor said it can be done if we can host the file in a repository and then link it to windows ODBC ? I'm not sure what does that means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to set up an EA project: stored in an .EAP file (accessed through the file system), or stored in a database (accessed through ODBC)

The file actually contains a database, and EA provides functionality for migrating both ways between the two.

An .EAP file can be accessed by several users simultaneously (with the file on a network drive), as of course a database can be. In either case, you are strongly encouraged to enable EA's "user security" in order to allow users to lock the parts of the project they are working on so they don't undo each others' changes.

An .EAP file can be used if the team is small. If there are more than 10 of you, you definitely want to set up a database repository.

So yes, several users can work in the same .EAP file. ODBC is a different way of setting it up; there is then no file as such but a database instead.

Comment: What do you mean by `The file actually contains a database`?

Comment: Precisely that. The file contains a database, specifically a JET database. Put another way, all EA projects are stored in databases. An .EAP project is just a database stored in a single file.

Answer (score 1):

See [Team Modeling Resources for Enterprise Architect](http://sparxsystems.com/resources/corporate/).