# How to merge EAP files in Enterprise Architect

Tags: merge, enterprise-architect

If two people are working on the same EAP file and later want to merge it. Can they do it?

Is it possible to merge two EAP files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**My original, accepted answer: (also note the 2018 update below)**

Have a look at this manual section:
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/projects_and_teams/teamdevelopment.html

As with all collaboration, there is a chance for raising conflicts when more that one person works on the same data.

From EA's side the most straightforward approach is the XMI transfer (import/export).

If you collaborate on a regular basis you might want to setup more advanced version control. (see above weblink) Careful, the feature availability depends on the EA version that you use.

[As pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653504/how-can-several-users-work-on-the-same-enterprise-architect-file-ea-collaborat) it is possible for small teams to access and work on the exact same file on the FS.

**Update from 2018:**

The user guide has been updated and is available through new URLs. [The current user guide page](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_repository/teamdevelopment.html) now differentiates methods for

1. network deployment of EA files
2. Replication (including a [sub-page that also deals with resolving merge conflicts](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_repository/replication.html))
3. XMI Export / Import

Comment: The page returns "The page you're looking for cannot be found."

Comment: @user2722077 Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile there is a 3rd party solution of LieberLieber avbailable, the Model Versioner, with which you can diff and merge EAP files on the model level:
https://lemontree.lieberlieber.com